# Stripe webhook authentication - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, webhooks

My ruby-on-rails application uses stripe for card payments. Stripe has a provision of webhooks through which it contacts back to my application and gives details about every transactions - succeeded or failed.

For this, I have in my controller something like this:

```
class StripeController < ApplicationController
  def webhook
    data_json = JSON.parse request.body.read
    p data_json['data']['object']['customer']
  end
```

My question is how can I validate the authenticity of this webhook? To my knowledge and understanding one can easily imitate this (man-in-the-middle attack).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Stripe's [webhooks documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#receiving-a-webhook):

> If security is a concern, or if it's important to confirm that Stripe sent the webhook, you should only use the ID sent in your webhook and should request the remaining details from the Stripe API directly.

Answer (score 10):

The gem `stripe_event` has it covered in a different way.

[Securing your webhook endpoint](https://github.com/integrallis/stripe_event#securing-your-webhook-endpoint) is done through Basic HTTP Authentication in `stripe_event` gem.

If only Stripe knows the basic authentication password, this ensures that the request really comes from Stripe. Here's what you do:

1. Arrange for a secret key to be available in your application's environment variables or secrets.yml file.
2. Configure StripeEvent to require that secret be used as a basic authentication password, using code along the lines:

   `StripeEvent.authentication_secret = ENV['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET']`
3. When you specify your webhook's URL in Stripe's settings, include the secret as a password in the URL, along with any username:

   `https://stripe:my-secret-key@myapplication.com/my-webhook-path`

This is only truly secure if your webhook endpoint is accessed over SSL, which Stripe strongly recommends anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You can enable `basic http authentication` for the stripe webhook events by setting the webhook to the following url

```
https://username:password@myapplication.com/my-webhook-path
```

This will result in a `Authorization` header with the value of

```
Basic encode64(username:password)
```

for instance by setting the webhook to the following url

```
https://admin:123456@myapplication.com/my-webhook-path
```

you will get this header in the inbound request

```
Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2
```